# Apache configuring a redirect for 404 behavior to try with .html suffix

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a safe way to prevent 404s with smart redirection.

http://www.domain.com/test (results in 404)
http://www.domain.com/test.html (results in page)

Is there a way I can configure Apache to try appending .html to the URL if the page is 404? So basically if I visit: http://www.domain.com/test Apache would say "this page doesn't exist, lets try adding .html suffix to it and see if that exists".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any real pages without .html ?

Comment: Yes. We do have some.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of configuring the apache I reverted to some logic in my application layer for these edge cases.